# Split dataset based on column value

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have a `Dataset<Row>` which is a resultant of Kafka `readStream` as shown below in Java code snippet.

```
m_oKafkaEvents = getSparkSession().readStream().format("kafka")  
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", strKafkaAddress)  
  .option("subscribe", getInsightEvent().getTopic())  
  .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", "100000")  
  .option("startingOffsets", "latest")  
  .option("failOnDataLoss", false)  
  .load()  
  .select(functions.from_json(functions.col("value").cast("string"), oSchema).as("events"))  
  .select("events.*");  

m_oKafkaEvents  
{  
    {"EventTime":"1527005246864000000","InstanceID":"231","Model":"Opportunity_1","Milestone":"OrderProcessed"},  
    {"EventTime":"1527005246864000002","InstanceID":"232","Model":"Opportunity_2","Milestone":"OrderProcessed"},  
    {"EventTime":"1527005246864000001","InstanceID":"233","Model":"Opportunity_1","Milestone":"OrderProcessed"},  
    {"EventTime":"1527005246864000002","InstanceID":"234","Model":"Opportunity_2","Milestone":"OrderProcessed"}  
}
```

I need to split this dataset based on column "Model" which would result in two Dataset as below;

```
 m_oKafkaEvents_for_Opportunity_1_topic 
   {  
       {"EventTime":"1527005246864000000","InstanceID":"231","Model":"Opportunity_1","Milestone":"OrderProcessed"},  
       {"EventTime":"1527005246864000001","InstanceID":"233","Model":"Opportunity_1","Milestone":"OrderProcessed"}   
   }  

   m_oKafkaEvents_for_Opportunity_2_topic  
   {  
      {"EventTime":"1527005246864000002","InstanceID":"232","Model":"Opportunity_2","Milestone":"OrderProcessed"},  
      {"EventTime":"1527005246864000002","InstanceID":"234","Model":"Opportunity_2","Milestone":"OrderProcessed"}  
   }
```

These Datasets would be published into Kafka sink. The topic name would be the model value. i.e `Opportunity_1` and `Opportunity_2`.
   Hence I need to have a handle column "Model" value and respective events list.
   Since am new to spark, am looking for help on how this can be achieved via java code.
   Appreciate any help.

Comment: corrected spellings, improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would look like:

```
allEvents.selectExpr("topic", "CONCAT('m_oKafkaEvents_for_', Model, '_topic')")
        .write()
        .format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
        .save();
```

You can see an example here https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#writing-the-output-of-batch-queries-to-kafka . But after looking at Spark's code, it seems that we can have only 1 topic/write, i.e. it'll chose as topic the first encountered row:

```
def write(
  sparkSession: SparkSession,
  queryExecution: QueryExecution,
  kafkaParameters: ju.Map[String, Object],
  topic: Option[String] = None): Unit = {
val schema = queryExecution.analyzed.output
validateQuery(schema, kafkaParameters, topic)
queryExecution.toRdd.foreachPartition { iter =>
  val writeTask = new KafkaWriteTask(kafkaParameters, schema, topic)
  Utils.tryWithSafeFinally(block = writeTask.execute(iter))(
    finallyBlock = writeTask.close())
}
```

You can try this approach though and tell here if it works as told above ? If it doesn't work, you have alternative solutions, as:

1. Cache main DataFrame and create 2 other DataFrames, filtered by Model attribute
2. Use foreachPartition and Kafka writer to send the messages without splitting the main dataset

The first solution is pretty easy to implement and you use all Spark facilities to do that. In the other side and at least theoritecally, splitting the dataset should be slightly slower than the second proposal. But try to measure before chosing one or another option, maybe the difference will be really small and it's always better to use clear and community-approven approach.

Below you can find some code showing both situations:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("JavaStructuredNetworkWordCount")
            .getOrCreate();
    Dataset<Row> allEvents = spark.readStream().format("kafka")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "")
            .option("subscribe", "event")
            .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", "100000")
            .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
            .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
            .load()
            .select(functions.from_json(functions.col("value").cast("string"), null).as("events"))
            .select("events.*");


    // First solution
    Dataset<Row> opportunity1Events = allEvents.filter("Model = 'Opportunity_1'");
    opportunity1Events.write().format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "")
            .option("topic", "m_oKafkaEvents_for_Opportunity_1_topic").save();
    Dataset<Row> opportunity2Events = allEvents.filter("Model = 'Opportunity_2'");
    opportunity2Events.write().format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "")
            .option("topic", "m_oKafkaEvents_for_Opportunity_2_topic").save();
    // Note: Kafka writer was added in 2.2.0 https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/b0a5cd89097c563e9949d8cfcf84d18b03b8d24c

    // Another approach with iteration throughout messages accumulated within each partition
    allEvents.foreachPartition(new ForeachPartitionFunction<Row>() {
        private KafkaProducer<String, Row> localProducer = new KafkaProducer<>(new HashMap<>());

        private final Map<String, String> modelsToTopics = new HashMap<>();
        {
            modelsToTopics.put("Opportunity_1", "m_oKafkaEvents_for_Opportunity_1_topic");
            modelsToTopics.put("Opportunity_2", "m_oKafkaEvents_for_Opportunity_2_topic");
        }

        @Override
        public void call(Iterator<Row> rows) throws Exception {
            // If your message is Opportunity1 => add to messagesOpportunity1
            // otherwise it goes to Opportunity2
            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                Row currentRow = rows.next();
                // you can reformat your row here or directly in Spark's map transformation
                localProducer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(modelsToTopics.get(currentRow.getAs("Model")),
                        "some_message_key", currentRow));
            }
            // KafkaProducer accumulates messages in a in-memory buffer and sends when a threshold was reached
            // Flush them synchronously here to be sure that every stored message was correctly
            // delivered
            // You can also play with features added in Kafka 0.11: the idempotent producer and the transactional producer
            localProducer.flush();
        }
    });
```